# Word Developer Content Control - Open Full XML Properties List

Tags: microsoft-word, developer-tools

While building a fillable document in Word, a form briefly popped up on the left side of my screen that allowed directly setting every available XML property for content controls -- such as CheckGrammar, CheckSpelling, PlaceholderText, etc.  It looks very similar to the Visual Studio properties editor.  Closed it when I finished working on that control, and cannot figure out how to reopen the panel again.

Can't seem to find anything that even says that is available, but I literally used it 30 minutes ago when it opened by accident.  Would love to know how to open that again, because the default Properties editor falls very short.

The closest I have found is the Properties editor for the ActiveX content controls, but that is not the type I was using in this document, and the parameters were very different.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in the controls section, you will have multiple different field types. The one you inserted was probably a field from the "ActiveX Controls" group:

[image]

When you insert such a field and then open the "Properties", you will find a huge "Properties" window, similar to the one in VB.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Your screenshot depicts exactly what I was looking for.  However..  when I add an ActiveX control and click properties now, I get a properties window, but it has FAR fewer--and very different--options.  My list starts with AutoSize and ends with WordWrap.

Comment: @Loeli I think that is because the image is showing the properties for a Word Document object, which has a very large number of properties. The built-in ActiveX objects *are* much simpler and have far fewer properties.

Comment: @Brad: jonsson is correct. In my screenshot, the window is showing the properties of the document object. If you open the dropdown at the very top where it says "ThisDocument Document", then you will be able to select other ActiveX form controls and that will of course change the editable properties.